# set of 0-combination of $\{1,...,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

What is the set of $0$-combinations of $\{1,...,n\}$.
The cardinality of this set is 1, so it can not be the empty set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\varnothing$ has cardinality $0$, sure. However, $\{\varnothing\}$ has cardinality $1$, and *that* is the set containing all $0$-combinations. There is one $0$-combination, and that's the empty set.